# Why Surf function is not working with simple data table in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a very simple set of data:

```
       A={1 4 7;2 5 8;3 6 9};
       X={1 2 3};
       Y={1;2;3};
       surf(X,Y,A)
```

will result in the following error:

```
       Error using surf (line 57)
       X,Y,Z, and c cannot be complex.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should actually say "X,Y,Z cannot be cell arrays". They have to be numeric arrays (and of course those arrays cannot contain complex numbers). In your case, you should just change curly braces to square braces:

```
A = [1 4 7;2 5 8;3 6 9];
X = [1 2 3];
Y = [1;2;3];
surf(X,Y,A)
```

Comment: Thank you, actually the error that I get was about the x,y,z, and c cannot be complex. but I guess that's because I use curly braces. I changed it and it works.